# How to hide a window, instead of exiting, when the top right cross button is pressed?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-tray

By default, a standard window created with:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
```

will be closed, causing the program to exit, when we click on the top right cross:

[image]

My program has a single such window, but also an always-present icon in the **system tray notification area**.

**How to make that clicking on the top right cross makes this window hidden, but does not exit the program?**

This didn't work in the main window message loop, the app is still exiting.

```
switch (msg) 
{
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
        break;
}
```

Comment: You should list what you've tried so far, and what search terms you've been using on google. This will help people answer your question (the reason I point this out is that some people may not answer because the question seems simple, and the lack of context may lead them assume the simple solution didn't work).

Comment: @JonKloske Sorry I forgot to add the code I tried, now fixed.

Comment: I think you have misidentified the problem here.  Clicking the close button sends a WM_CLOSE message, which destroys the window by default, but does not cause the application to exit.  Try setting breakpoints on PostQuitMessage and ExitProcess.

Comment: You should probably also show us what message hooks you're using to receive into that switch statement. At least one site on a short google journey suggests ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND with the SC_CLOSE message in that. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @JonKloske DefWindowProc will send WM_CLOSE when it gets SC_CLOSE.

Comment: Saw your answer seconds after pressing enter ;)

Comment: @JonKloske: `ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND` is an MFC macro. The MFC do not apply here. This question is asking about the Windows API.

Comment: Yep, was just trying to get the OP to add some more info. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DefWindowProc` calls `DestroyWindow` when it gets `WM_CLOSE` so all you have to do is not pass the message to `DefWindowProc`:

```
switch (msg) 
{
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
        return 0;
}
```

`DestroyWindow` alone will not exit a program with a "normal" message loop. It is usually the `WM_QUIT` message you generate in your main windows `WM_DESTROY` with `PostQuitMessage` that causes your message loop to stop and exit the program...